# How do I delete multiple records using REST API in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hello I am new to Spring Boot, I have developed the API to get, create and delete a single record by ID, now I want to make a request to delete selected multiple records. Example: I like to delete 4 records out of 10 records in a single request instead of making 4 delete requests.

ProjectController.java

```
@Qualifier("projectServiceImpl")
@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

@Autowired
private MapValidationErrorService mapValidationErrorService;

@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<?> createNewProject(@Valid @RequestBody Project project, BindingResult result){

    ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.MapValidationService(result);
    if(errorMap!=null) return errorMap;

    Project project1 = projectService.saveOrUpdateProject(project);
    return new ResponseEntity<Project>(project1, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> findProjectById(@PathVariable Long id){
    Project project = projectService.findProjectById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<Project>(project, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("")
public List<Project> getAllProjects(){return projectService.findAllProjects();}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteProject(@PathVariable Long id){
    projectService.deleteProjectById(id);

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Project with id: '"+id+ "' was deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

ProjectServiceImpl.java

```
@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

@Override
public long count() {
    return projectRepository.count();
}

public Project saveOrUpdateProject(Project project){
    try{
        project.setProjectNumber(project.getProjectNumber());
        return projectRepository.save(project);
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new ProjectNumberException("The project number "+project.getProjectNumber()+" is already existed. Please select a different project number.");
    }
}

public Project findProjectById(Long id) {
    return projectRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

public List<Project> findAllProjects() {
    return projectRepository.findAll();
}

public void deleteProjectById(Long id) {
    Project project = projectRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);;
    projectRepository.delete(project);
}
```

ProjectRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Project> {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a method like this in the `ProjectRepository`

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Project where id in (:ids)")
int deleteByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

You need an endpoint to process such JSON request

```
{
  "ids" : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: Could you give me the methods for Service and Controller layer also? I still get confused.

Comment: for example, I want my delete request param to be like /id=2&id=4&id=5 what should I do? I am front-end dev so I can't understand these things so well.

Comment: @jakeywang You can use such multiple parameters with Spring, but better to pass a JSON with ids in the request body, like with POST request.

Comment: Make sure to add @Transactional as well. To avoid concurrency issues

Comment: @DeepanshuRathi `@Transactional` will not help with concurrency issues. And It doesn't need here — base repository has this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Below solution solved my problem:

ProjectController.java:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteProject(@RequestBody Long[] ids){
projectService.deleteProjectById(ids);

return new ResponseEntity<String>("Project with ids: '"+ids+ "' was deleted", 
HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

ProjectServiceImpl.java

```
public void deleteProjectById(Long[] ids) {
  for (Long id : ids) {
  Project project = projectRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
  projectRepository.delete(project);
  }
}
```